# Generic query in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, generics, search

I want to make a generic search UserControl in wpf. I want it to get a collection of objects and a name of a property to search by. 
The problem is I can't use generics because the code that calls the search function also can't know of the type.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or some way to query an Object that is underneath another type?

Comment: "and a name of a property" What property?

Comment: The property by which to search. For example, if I search Person, I would pass the property name of "Full Name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example.

```
interface IFoo
    {

    }
    class Bar1 : IFoo
    {
        //interface implementations
        public string Property1 { get; set; }

        public string myProperty1 { set; get; }
    }

    class Bar2 : IFoo
    {
        //interface implementations
        public string Property1 { get; set; }

        public string myProperty1 { set; get; }
    }


    //Search the list of objects and access the original values.
    List<IFoo> foos = new List<IFoo>();
        foos.Add(new Bar1
        {
            Property1 = "bar1",
            myProperty1 ="myBar1"
        });
        foos.Add(new Bar1());

        foos.Add(new Bar2());
        foos.Add(new Bar2());

        //Get the objects.
        foreach (var foo in foos)
        {
            //you can access foo directly without knowing the original class.
            var fooProperty = foo.Property1;

            //you have to use reflection to get the original type and its properties and methods
            Type type = foo.GetType();
            foreach (var propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
            {
                var propName = propertyInfo.Name;
                var propValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(foo);
            }
        }


var result = list.Where(a => a.propertyName);
```

Comment: I am aware that if all classes derive from the same empty interface, i can access the object without knowing the type. But the List.Where() expression still does not work

Comment: @TomerAgmon1, the one that I wrote does not contain Where(). You can use it without any problems I tested and it was working.

Comment: You can get all the types and their properties and methods with just using Refection.

Comment: And hence, it does not answer my question. Could you please elaborate on using the Where method?

Comment: I am not sure you understand. I want to filter a list by a property that is given as input. I understand how to get the name of the property by input, but how do I filter the list using Where?  The above example given to me did not work

Comment: Please, check the result it is in the bellow of the code.

Comment: No reflection means your client does not need to have any information about your classes. you can remove the property and it works.

Comment: Please, check the code again I removed the property from interface. The interface is empty now.

Comment: Never mind. The above example does work. Many thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. If any questions please, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Data = new List<object>() { new A() { MyProperty = "abc" }, new B() { MyProperty = "cde"} };

        var Result = Data.Where(d => (d.GetType().GetProperty("MyProperty").GetValue(d) as string).Equals("abc"));

        // Result is IEnumerable<object> wich contains one A class object ;)
    }
}

class A
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: By using p.Name.Equals you're assuming p is a class with a property called name, and you search only by it. As i explained, for it to be generic, p is an object and the property to search by is only known to me by it's name via string

Comment: If i understand You correctly: .GetType().GetProperty("name").GetValue(foo)

Comment: Would that work? I'll give it a go. Also, Data in the example above is IQueriable? If i have a list do i do: List.AsQueriable().GetType....?

Comment: The logic is good, but the code does not work. First d. GetType() returns objects, which has no properties that i care about. But, if i change it to an interface from which all classes derive from, it works. Even though, the query returns nothing. If i replace "d"  in the lambda expression with (Data[0]) it does work... Which means something in the syntax of your example is wrong